# Error in downloading the image from the storage in firebase Firestore database

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, storage

[image]I am using firebase storage to store images and firebase firestore to store data and image url of the storage.

I am getting the following error while downloading the image

> java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not
>   Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}

Below is the postAdapter class which is then used in the fragment to retrieve the list.

Please let me know where I am going wrong in this.

```
public class PostsAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<PostsModel, PostsAdapter.PostsHolder> {
    private OnItemClickListener listener;
    private View.OnClickListener buttonListener;
    private Context mContext;

    private String id;

    //boolean likechecker = false;

    private static final String TAG = "DocSnippets";
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile_pic");


    public PostsAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<PostsModel> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostsHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final PostsModel model) {
        //retrieve the fields here
           final String documentId = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();

        holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getPostContent());
        holder.textViewSpinnerC.setText(model.getPost_author_spinnerC());
        holder.textViewCategory.setText(model.getPostcategory());
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getPostTitle());
        holder.textViewPostUsername.setText(model.getPost_author_username());


       storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
                holder.postUserImage.setImageURI(uri);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
            }
        });


        holder.commentsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent toCommentActivity = new Intent(view.getContext(), CommentActivity.class);
               toCommentActivity.putExtra("PostKey", documentId);
                view.getContext().startActivity(toCommentActivity);


            }
        }); }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_list_layout,
                parent, false);
        return new PostsHolder(v);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int position) {
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener postKey) {
    }


    class PostsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        TextView textViewTitle;
        TextView textViewDescription;
        TextView textViewSpinnerC;
        TextView textViewCategory;
        TextView textViewPostUsername;

        TextView textViewTime;

        CircleImageView postUserImage;

        ImageButton favPostButton;
        Button commentsbutton;


        public PostsHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_title);
            textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_description);
            textViewTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_time);
             commentsbutton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commenting_button);
             favPostButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
             textViewSpinnerC = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_SpinnerC);
             textViewCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_Category);
             postUserImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_user_profile_image);
             textViewPostUsername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_username);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                        listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                    }
                }
            });



        }
    }



    public interface OnClickListener
    {
        void OnClickListener(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);

    }
    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.buttonListener = onClickListener;
    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

Comment: It properly says the image does not exist please post the Storage Screenshot.

Comment: but image does exist, i have verified it

Comment: Please post the image storage location in proper manner.

Comment: this the download URL, i hope it will work, there is a folder in profile_pic in which images are stored    https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blogapp2-fd88b.appspot.com/o/profile_pic%2FcdKsQsX9B5euk1RMGJ3E7KzqIix2?alt=media&token=589f03bb-917c-4558-816a-90f7294b23a2

Comment: Sir your not getting my point. I want storage location similar like this : `gs://xx.appspot.com/images/6g74sRdiPh5BVApVtOFM.jpg`.

Comment: Sir here it is gs://blogapp2-fd88b.appspot.com/profile_pic/cdKsQsX9B5euk1RMGJ3E7KzqIix2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199166/discussion-between-ashish-and-ramneek-kashyap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided the user profile image url in Database. Try using picasso

```
Picasso.get().load(model.getPost_user_profile_pic_url()).into(holder.postUserImage);
```